# OutputStream not sending until socket is closed

Tags: android, sockets, outputstream

Hi i'm developing an android app for controlling computer using sockets, but my problem is i don't get data from server until i close the outputstream thus closing socket and won't be able to send or receive data anymore. My question is how can i send data from server to client without closing the OutputStream ?

This code is working with closing the OutputStream (ps1.close()) : socket is closed

```
private class Receivecmd extends Thread{
        Scanner sc = null;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Runtime r;
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                while(true)
                {
                    if(sc.hasNext())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Got Some");
                        String sr = sc.nextLine();
                        if(sr.contains("shutdown "))
                        {
                            if(sr.contains("/h"))
                            {
                                sr = sr.replace("/t", "");
                            }
                            r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            r.exec(sr+"/f");
                        }
                        else if (sr.contains("taskman"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Task");
                            r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            Process p = r.exec("tasklist.exe");
                            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
                            PrintStream ps1 = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            while(sc1.hasNext())
                            {
                                String s = sc1.nextLine();
                                ps1.println(s);
                                System.out.println(s);

                            }
                            ps1.close();

                        }
                        else if(sr.contains(".exe"))
                        {
                            r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            r.exec(sr);
                            System.out.println(sr);
                        }


                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AndroidServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            super.run(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
```

This code is not working when i delete ps1.close() : i can still receive data

```
private class Receivecmd extends Thread{
        Scanner sc = null;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Runtime r;
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                while(true)
                {
                    if(sc.hasNext())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Got Some");
                        String sr = sc.nextLine();
                        if(sr.contains("shutdown "))
                        {
                            if(sr.contains("/h"))
                            {
                                sr = sr.replace("/t", "");
                            }
                            r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            r.exec(sr+"/f");
                        }
                        else if (sr.contains("taskman"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Task");
                            r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            Process p = r.exec("tasklist.exe");
                            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
                            PrintStream ps1 = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            while(sc1.hasNext())
                            {
                                String s = sc1.nextLine();
                                ps1.println(s);
                                System.out.println(s);

                            }


                        }
                        else if(sr.contains(".exe"))
                        {
                            r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            r.exec(sr);
                            System.out.println(sr);
                        }


                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AndroidServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            super.run(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
```

Comment: why you don't want to close the stream?

Comment: @JordiCastilla when i close the stream it closes the socket so i won't be able to send or receive data anymore

Comment: This code sends all right, every time `ps1` is flushed. What does the receiving code look like?

Comment: It looks like : Scanner sc = new Scanner (socket.getInputStream); while (sc.hasNext ()){tasklist.add (sc.nextLine ();} (where tasklist is a string arraylist)

Comment: Great. What is `taskList`? Where is the evidence that data isn't being received?

Comment: I'm using this scanner to put all the lines caught from the input stream to an arraylist of strings called tasklist when the scanner is finished i'm doing a for loop to append all the lines from the arraylist to a TextView and thus seeing it. It works with ps1.close () but it closes the socket too which i don't want

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flush()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html)

> Flushes the object by writing out any buffered data to the underlying output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the receiver processes the input line by line, so you should append one.

```
ps1.println();
```

Comment: i don't get it. Where am i supposed to append this line.

Comment: I don't know who processes your output, and in what way, but I assume it is processed line by line. So you should append a new line to the end of a meaningful command, otherwise the receiver will never read a single line, except when you close the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using this scanner to put all the lines caught from the input stream to an arraylist of strings called tasklist

In other words you're reading the input until end of stream, which only occurs when you close or shutdown the socket at the sender.

You could shut it down for output, but that implies you can only do one of these request/response cycles. You need to reconsider your application protocol. Or else just process one task at a time.